# Mercurial to Git conversion: DLLs differ - why?

Tags: git, dll, mercurial, repository

I'm converting a bunch of repositories from Mercurial to Git using the scripts of the fast-export.git repo (git://repo.or.cz/fast-export.git).

One repository contains binary data (executables and DLLs) - converting this repository never leads to identical data. After conversion, some of the DLLs (and only DLLs!) are not binary equal. (Please, no discussion on binary data in Git - I know this is bad, however, I just have to do the conversion.)

It does not matter if I am doing the conversion on Windows or Linux and I also tried different settings with no difference. Does someone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Either Git or Mercurial thinks the file is text perhaps? Do you have any sort of automatic-line-ending-fixer-upper enabled in one of the tools? Both tools should treat files are pure binary in the backend if I'm not mistaken, if you do a diff it should start looking at it from a text point of view, but I think both tools have extensions for automatically handling line-ending differences between platforms. Could be that they trip up?

Comment: Not being familiar with "git fast-export", I read this - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-export - which says: "This program dumps the given revisions in a form suitable to be piped into git fast-import.". Are you sure they output the files in their original representation suitable for use by anything other than git fast-import?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @LasseV.Karlsen - I did experiment with some of the line ending settings as this was my first suspicion as well, unfortunately with no success. It's also funny that only DLLs seem to be affected, no other binary files (like executables)...

Comment: 1) read https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes, prepare **specially** .gitattributes for *.dll before fast-export OR 2) don't use fast-export, Mercurial+hggit will be OK